# Como definir níveis de acesso

Tags: php

Eu tenho um sistema que possui uma tabela pv_usuario e uma pv_cargo.
Gostaria de fazer uma verificação de acordo com o cargo o usuário será redirecionado para página diferente.  
Tenho o código abaixo:

```
$result = "select * from pv_usuario where login = '$login' and senha = '$senha' and ativo = 1";
$sql_execute = mysql_query($result);
$sql_verifica = mysql_num_rows($sql_execute);

    if($sql_verifica > 0)
    {
        if($senha == 'giga123' )
          {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
            $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
            header('location:../../mpv/Login/reset.php');
          }
          else {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
            $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
            header('location:../../mpv/index.php');
            exit;
        }

    }else 
        {
           session_destroy();
           unset($_SESSION['login']);
           unset($_SESSION['senha']);
           session_destroy();
           header('location:../../mpv/acesso_negado.php');
            exit;
        }
```

Pensei em fazer algo do tipo e coloquei dentro do primeiro if acima:

```
$query = $con->query("select * from pv_usuario where login = '$login' and ativo = 1");
while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) 
{
if( $reg["cod_usuario"] == 1 ) 
  {
      header('location:../../mpv/Atendimento/index.php');
  }
  else if($reg["cod_usuario"] == 2)
  {
      header('location:../../mpv/Tecnico/index.php');
  }
}
```

Só que não está funcionando. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que o problema está aqui: `$reg["cod_usuario"]` tenta mudar pra isso: `$reg["COD_USUARIO"]`

Comment: Algumas observações: 1- Qual o tipo de erro que está dando?
2- O campo "cod_usuario" pertence a tabela "pv_usuario" mesmo, certo?
3- Nos códigos não cita o "pv_cargo" em nenhum lugar, acredito que esteja fazendo testes com usuários específicos, certo?
4- Se o segundo bloco de código está dentro do primeiro IF (if($sql_verifica > 0)), não há necessidade da segunda query, isso pode te economizar um pouco de código :)

Comment: A, e tambem acredito que será necessário utilizar um indentificador de linha, no seu caso `$reg[0]["COD_USUARIO"]`

Comment: você não esqueceu de dar um `exit` depois do `header('Location: ...')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para começar aconselho-te a alterar o [mysql_](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php) para [mysqli_](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) uma vez que a versão [mysql_](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php) será descontinuada.

Se quiseres manter a versão com o nome do campo `$reg["cod_usuario"]` em vez de utilizares o `$query->fetch_array()` podes utilizar `$query->fetch_assoc()` que te resolve o problema.

Ou então se quiseres continuar com o `$query->fetch_array()` podes passar como parâmetro o tipo de dados que queres receber como nesse exemplo:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* ARRAY NÚMERICO */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);  

/* ARRAY ASSOCIATIVO */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);  

/* ARRAY NÚMERICO E ASSOCIATIVO */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);
```

[Fonte do exemplo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#example-1592).

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17002/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-fabricio-wm).

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendo [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) por inúmeras vantagens. Você decide, mas como o @Jorge B. falou, evite mysql_. Estou dando um exemplo com PDO.

```
// Exemplo de conexão com PDO:
$pdo = new \PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=suaTabela' , 'usuario' , 'senha' );
$stmt = $pdo-> prepare( "select * from pv_usuario where login = '$login' and ativo = 1" );
$stmt-> execute();
$row = $stmt-> fetch( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

// Validando o tipo de cadastro:
if( $row["cod_usuario"] == 1 )
{
    // redirecionamento com caminho absoluto.
    header("location: http://www.example.com/mpv/Atendimento/index.php");
}
elseif($row["cod_usuario"] == 2 )
{
    // redirecionamento com caminho absoluto.
    header("location: http://www.example.com/mpv/Tecnico/index.php");
}
```